# Reddit OAuth2 API circular redirect

Tags: java, apache, http, kotlin, reddit

I am attempting to send a `POST` authorization request to the Reddit API to get an access token, following this documentation: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/oauth2

I am getting the following exception thrown when I execute the request:

> Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token'

Here is the `Kotlin` code which uses `Apache Commons HTTP`:

```
@Test
fun testOauthAuthenticationManual() {

    val client = DefaultHttpClient()
    client.redirectStrategy = LaxRedirectStrategy()
    val post = HttpPost("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token")
    post.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic a3E0RWVocURGeWVoUWc6UVYyYjU0cldDeTJ4aHNZc292ZXNTcVVQc2tJ")
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    post.addHeader("User-Agent", "Just testing")
    post.addHeader("Host", "reddit.com")

    val parameters = listOf<NameValuePair>(
            BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
            BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "http://address.co.uk"),
            BasicNameValuePair("code", "2dYqDpjs6lA7FVvUILgDaxKS2ww"))

    post.entity = UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, "UTF-8")

    try {
        val response = client.execute(post)
        if (response.statusLine.statusCode == 200) {
            // continue
        } else {
            throw HttpClientException(response.statusLine.reasonPhrase)
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw HttpClientException("Could not execute HTTP request: ", e)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in setting up my request?

Comment: 301 is more an information than an error, it's possible the only thing you're doing wrong is not following that redirection. You should probably check the Location field of the 301 response to see if it's expected though (e.g. you app's `redirect_uri`).

Comment: @Aaron The `Location` field of the 301 response has the same uri: https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token

Comment: Hmmm yeah that's definitely weird. I can't see anything wrong with your code, I guess you'll have to wait for someone familiar with reddit's OAuth

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone else gets this error - the issue was fixed by removing:

```
post.addHeader("User-Agent", "Just testing")
post.addHeader("Host", "reddit.com")
```